# Angular 4 Unit Tests Attributes of child components

Tags: unit-testing, angular, jasmine

I'm upgrading an Angular 2 app to version 4.0.1, and i'm having troubles with some tests.

I'm trying to get the attributes of a child component and test that the value given is correct.

Unfortunately, the attributes seems to be undefined in the test context, even when the component behave correctly in JiT build and AoT build.

The tests only broke after updating to Angular 4.0.1

Template of my parent component :

```
<div>
  <div *ngIf="isComponentEnabled">
    <child-component
      superBaseUrl="super_url" i18n-superBaseUrl="frk|"
      [slug]="slug"
      [name]="name"
      [age]="age">
    </child-component>
    .....

  </div>
</div>
```

Test that breaks :

```
     it(`GIVEN parent-component
      THEN it should have correct attribute values`, () => {
      componentInstance.name = 'Bar';
      componentInstance.age = 90;
      componentInstance.slug = 'foo';

      attributes = specService.queryAttributes(
        componentFixture, 'child-component');

      console.log('HEYA -> ', specService.queryDebugElement(
        componentFixture, 'child-component'));
      expect(attributes['superbaseurl']).toBe('super_url');
      expect(attributes['i18n-superbaseurl']).toBe('frk|');
      expect(attributes['ng-reflect-slug']).toBe('foo');
      expect(attributes['ng-reflect-name']).toBe('Bar');
      expect(attributes['ng-reflect-age']).toBe('90');
    });
```

Ouput of the breaking test :

```
Expected undefined to be 'foo'.
Expected undefined to be 'Bar'.
Expected undefined to be '90'.
```

Console log inside the test :

```
<child-component _ngcontent-c115="" i18n-superbaseurl="frk|" superbaseurl="super_url">
</child-component>
```

So i don't understand why in version 4 the attributes are not generated in this context. In version 2.X.X, we had the ng-reflect but it seems that this is no longer the case.

I've also tried to add a basic attribute (toto="toto") in the template, and this one shows up in the console.log of the test.

**Does anybody have an idea why the attributes no longer shows up ?**

P.S: The specService.queryAttributes is just a wrapper that call detectChanges before querying the attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it !

For anyone interested, you have to add every sub components and compile them in version 4.0.1 in your TestBed if you want the attributes to be queryable.

In version 2.X, that was not required.

**EDIT**

Also, see, https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/15822 because i don't know if this is intended or not.

Comment: Can you illustrate?